# UITableViewCell detail indicators flying around

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` added to a `UIViewController` inside a `UIView`. The table view has constraints to fit the size of it's parent view. The view has constraints for it's position and size. If I animate the size of this view, the table view shows new rows, but the new elements, which about to appear, seem to fly around from their initial (not set) position. For example, the right detail indicator of the `UITableViewCell` flies from the left edge of the cell, the text labels from a slightly different position, etc.

[image: Things flying around]

I do the animation like this:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = blah;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

As you can see, the data reloading takes place before the animation block. Once the animation was played, changing the view size does not animate the table view's contents anymore (I guess it does, but everything is in their place already.)

How can I prevent animating the elements and keep the animation of the frame?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at calling [setAnimationsEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationsEnabled:) on the cells or maybe the cells accessory view.

Comment: This is a class method. I think disabling animations affects every animated object, not just specific views.